# how to import android experimental module

Tags: android, gradle-experimental

i have experimental(v:0.4.0) android module that use gradle file with model block like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.mode.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 21
    buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.example.native_libs"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    }
}

compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

/*
 * native build settings
 */
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native_libs"
    stl = "stlport_static"
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
    cppFlags.add("-std=gnu++11")
    ldLibs.add("z")
    /*
     * Other ndk flags configurable here are
     * cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
     * cppFlags.add("-fno-exceptions")
     * ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
     * stl       = "system"
     */
}
android.buildTypes {
    debug {
        ndk.with {
            debuggable = true
        }
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
    }
}

android.productFlavors {
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    create("arm") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
    }
    create("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
    }
    create("arm8") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
    }
    create("x86") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
    }
    create("x86-64") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
    }
    create("mips") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
    }
    create("mips-64") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
    }
    // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
    create("all")
}}
```

and now like another module, we can't import java wrapper classes in this module that use experimental plugin.

i change apply `plugin: 'com.android.mode.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.mode.library'` but nothing changed and still can't recognize java wrapper classes in native_libs module :(

how to config gradle for native module library?
why experimental plugin don't let to import module, like normal way for other modules?

**[edit]**

i read this doc 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental
but there is not way to import modules that combine native(c/c++) and java.

Answer (score 0):

i find a project in github that done what i want to do :)

https://github.com/frogermcs/FlatBuffs